# JavaScript callbacks function object

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

i try to learn node.js and try to create a new TCP Server connection. The code

```
var server = require('net').createServer(function(socket) {
  console.log('new connection');

  socket.setEncoding('utf8');

  socket.write("Hello! You can start typing. Type 'quit' to exit.\n");

  socket.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('got:', data.toString());
    if (data.trim().toLowerCase() === 'quit') {
      socket.write('Bye bye!');
      return socket.end();
    }
    socket.write(data);
  });

  socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Client connection ended');
  });

}).listen(4001);
```

look at the callback function, after then, they call listen method. What is this for kind of object.

Comment: Could you re-state your question?  It's a bit difficult to understand in its current phrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it basically says is:

```
function myHandler(socket) {
   // everything up to socket.on('end')
}

var server = require('net').createServer(myHandler);
server.listen(4001);
```

So it's just creating a socket server with a handler function, and then make the server listen to port 4001.

Comment: method listen() is a function from server object. I see. Thanks so much